# Curious about the algorithm behind the persoanlization feature of spotify

Tags: api, spotify, mahout-recommender

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-users-top-artists-and-tracks/

> Get a User’s Top Artists and Tracks
> Get the current user’s top artists or tracks based on calculated affinity.
>
> Affinity is a measure of the expected preference a user has for a particular >track or artist.  It is based on user behavior, including play history, but >does not include actions made while in incognito mode. Light or infrequent >users of Spotify may not have sufficient play history to generate a full >affinity data set.
>
> As a user’s behavior is likely to shift over time, this preference data is >available over three time spans. See time_range in the query parameter table >for more information.
>
> For each time range, the top 50 tracks and artists are available for each user. >In the future, it is likely that this restriction will be relaxed. This data is >typically updated once each day for each user.

I am wondering which algorithm is used for implementing this feature? colloborative filtering algorithm or content based algorithm.